# How to provide Total number of rows while using PageFactory.createOffsetBasedPage

Tags: graphql-spqr, graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter

As per the relay specs, total number of rows should be provided in the connection itself. But I couldn't find a way to provide total number of rows or page count etc...

https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/

I am referring below sample provided for relay based pagination.

https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr-samples/blob/master/spring-boot-starter-sample/src/main/java/io/leangen/graphql/samples/repo/ProjectRepo.java

Answer (score 0):

That's a curious case. [Relay Connection spec](https://relay.dev/graphql/connections.htm) actually does *not* mention `totalCount` in the `Connection` object, but their [examples](https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/) randomly include that field anyway.

Either way, you can extends SPQR's `Page` as you see fit. You can have a look at the [`testExtendedPageMapping` test](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr/blob/0124fa44f817252063eb5c46150f0681f2e6bb24/src/test/java/io/leangen/graphql/RelayTest.java#L136) which [makes use](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr/blob/0124fa44f817252063eb5c46150f0681f2e6bb24/src/test/java/io/leangen/graphql/RelayTest.java#L480) of a custom [`ExtendedPage`](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr/blob/0124fa44f817252063eb5c46150f0681f2e6bb24/src/test/java/io/leangen/graphql/RelayTest.java#L527).

The resolver itself looks like this:

```java
@GraphQLQuery(name = "extended")
public ExtendedPage<Book> getExtended(
                              @GraphQLArgument(name = "first") int limit,
                              @GraphQLArgument(name = "after") String after) {
    long offset = Long.parseLong(after);
    List<Book> books = db.queryForBooks(limit, offset);
    long totalCount = db.getTotalCount();
    //Create ExtendedPage that has totalCount field
    return PageFactory.createOffsetBasedPage(books, totalCount, offset, 
                (edges, info) -> new ExtendedPage<>(edges, info, totalCount));
}
```

`ExtendedPage` is a simple implementation of `Page`:

```java
public class ExtendedPage<N> implements Page<N> {

    private final List<Edge<N>> edges;
    private final PageInfo pageInfo;
    private final long totalCount;

    ExtendedPage(List<Edge<N>> edges, PageInfo pageInfo, long totalCount) {
        this.edges = edges;
        this.pageInfo = pageInfo;
        this.totalCount = totalCount;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Edge<N>> getEdges() {
        return edges;
    }

    @Override
    public PageInfo getPageInfo() {
        return pageInfo;
    }

    public long getTotalCount() {
        return totalCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: But I would like to return the total number of rows back to the UI/as service call result in the http response.

Comment: @AmitJolly I understand you better now. I edited my answer accordingly.